# How is it possible that validation MSE is low while test MSE is really high?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

I'm having the following problem. I'm training a neural network LSTM using keras with the following architecture:

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
#model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam())
```

The training phase goes pretty smoothly: the training loss begins at around 12000 and descreases a lot in the first epoch to around 10-*ish*.

My data is a time-series with 5 variables and I'm trying to predict one of these variables. My data is sampled at second-rate. This data consists of sensor readings of an industrial machine.

I'm using the following function to generate the datasets (previously divided into train, valid and test):

```py
def create_dataset(X, y, time_steps):
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
        v = X.iloc[i:(i + time_steps)].values
        Xs.append(v)
        ys.append(y.iloc[i + time_steps])
    return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)
```

From the 5 variables of the original data, three of those variables are scaled between maximum and minimum value. **The target variable is not scaled**.

First of all, this is the loss and valid_loss plot after 10 epochs of training:

[image]

This behaviour is weird right? I would say the model is overfitting.

Now, to the main problem:

Although the validation metrics are reasonably good, when I make predictions this is happening:

Predictions:

[image]

Predictions with true value for the test set:

[image]

I would say that my network is capable of understanding the "pattern", but its not working in the same scale. Why is this happening?
1
When I measure the test MSE I got, as expected quite a high value - 82.

Comment: Looks like some scaling issues between different portions of the datasets that you use for training, testing, and validation...

Comment: I tried standardizing the variables, but now I have another problem: the training loss increases during training!